# How to use QPixmap so that only the project folder has to be used in the address

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qpixmap

I am using QPixmap in order to output pictures to my GUI and I have it working so far as such:

```
QPixmap background("C:/Users/sam/OOC++/CarProject/Images/Background.png");
```

But I realised that in doing this that if I wanted to use this code in another place, such as someone else's computer that this wouldn't work as they will not necessarily have the picture in the same place.

So I just wanted to know if there was a better, more general way of doing this. I was hoping that there was a shortcut so that it would go directly to the project that is being used and look there automatically so that I could just have something like:

```
QPixmap background("Images/Background.png");
```

Cheers!

Comment: why do not you use a qresource? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: I'm having some trouble trying to implement it at the moment, are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: If you want to do it, the image must have a relative path to the .exe, not your project. What is the relative path of the image with respect to your executable that is in the build folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the path relative to the executable and then use 
`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`
to build the right path. You can use install command to copy the images automaticaly after build.

Or better solution would be to put the image in the resource file.
Then you specify the path in the code like for ex. `":/Images/Background.png"`

Answer (score 0):

use 'u' before file path. It will allow to use relative file path.

```
(u"Images/cancel.png")
```

Comment: Is this for C++ or Python?

Comment: I have used in python, i am not sure about c++

Comment: I see. I thought it was C++ since OP tagged the question with C++ tag